# ML noise filtering

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, noise-reduction

Given an image (2048x2018) with a lot of noise of random pixels (>90% for each possible image), there are several pixels of the same color distributed across entire image. I want to remove noise and leave only pixels of the same color. Let's say from all random pixels 10 red, 15 orange and 14 black pixels should be left.

However, colors of repeating pixels are not known beforehand. There are multiple images with different colors. So I'm trying to write an algorithm that would filter an image until only repeating colors are left. Number of repeating colors should be as close as possible to actual number, but not necessarily exact.

I think this can be achieved by building a network to filter the noise out. But the data seem to be too random to use conventional networks since there are no patterns except of repeating pixels. Is there a way to calcify distributed values without any real pattern? Maybe there is any another way to do it without brute force sorting of each color?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GrantMiller Pooling - taking one block and scanning image. This does not work because color is not dominant in the block and gets replaced by other random color along the way.
Hashing colors and checking hit count - again, too many random colors in the same range, does not work with unique colors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use some sort of pooling, specifically **[Average Pooling](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-benefit-of-using-average-pooling-rather-than-max-pooling)**. You could use pooling to first find out what colors are dominant in the image, and then remove pixels of all colors other than the dominant colors to leave only the colors that you want.

Comment: This would only work if colors would be truly dominant, as it is now - most of the image is noise and there are few specific colors that stands out. Assuming that I would average 9x9 blocks, usually the color itself wont even be dominant in that block (<10% probability of it being there at all). That means average pooling would create average for each block of the image, thus blending those colors and providing incorrect result.